# NGINX Worker Process, Burst Read Speed to only 1918kb/s

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, performance

I am running an NGINX/1.8 server on Centos6.6 with multiple worker_processes, however while observing iotop I notice they burst up to 1918kb/s Read speed and rarely if at all pass that limit.

I want to be able to read my files and serve them faster (I am serving large files), Is this a linux limit I may have on processes or is this a misconfiguration of my nginx server.

```
Total DISK READ: 7.49 M/s | Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                          
 8840 be/4 nginx    1917.09 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % nginx: worker process
 9035 be/4 nginx    1917.09 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % nginx: worker process
 9051 be/4 nginx    1917.09 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % nginx: worker process
 9058 be/4 nginx    1917.09 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % nginx: worker process
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
    # For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user              nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 4000;
    accept_mutex off;
    use epoll;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    access_log off;



    access_log off;
    sendfile on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 1m;

    tcp_nodelay on; 
    output_buffers 1 8m;

client_body_buffer_size 10K;
client_header_buffer_size 1k;
client_max_body_size 8m;
large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    keepalive_requests 100000;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    open_file_cache          max=20000 inactive=1m;
    open_file_cache_valid    1m;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
    open_file_cache_errors   on;

}
```

Comment: related to: http://serverfault.com/a/705523/61607

Comment: What is disk type? Measure the read:write with dd, probably the bottleneck is the disk itself, need to find out more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think the static files are cached by the OS the first time they are read. They are never read again and don't generate any IO for iotop.

The 1918 kb/s must be the logs being written to disk for the request(s).

What is the actual download speed for clients downloading these files? Suggest `httperf` command to do quick performance test and simulate multiple clients.